# how to mock two functions using unittests mock.patch

Tags: python, testing, mocking

I need to mock two functions inside my API post method.
Mocking just one function worked well, but I have no idea how to do it when i need to mock two functions?

```
@unittest.mock.patch('path.to.first.function.thefirstfunction')
def test_connector_post(mock_thefirstfunction):
...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you can probably stack the decorators!

Comment: thanks @ti7, it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stack the decorators!

```py
@unittest.mock.patch("functionA")
@unittest.mock.patch("functionB")
def test_foo(...):
    ...
```